# How to fix FileNotFoundError [WinError 2]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to port the Proton-VPN Linux CLI (https://github.com/ProtonVPN/linux-cli) to Windows and have had decent success so far, but I'm running into an issue with [subprocess.Popen()]. I've tried many fixes but none have worked so far. I've tried converting this:

```
    with open(os.path.join(CONFIG_DIR, "ovpn.log"), "w+") as f:
        subprocess.Popen(
            [
                "openvpn",
                "--config", OVPN_FILE,
                "--auth-user-pass", PASSFILE,
                "--dev", "proton0",
                "--dev-type", "tun"
            ],
            stdout=f, stderr=f
        )
```

which is from the original module, to this:

```
    file_name = os.path.join(CONFIG_DIR, "ovpn.log")
    print(file_name)
    with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        subprocess.Popen([
            "openvpn",
            "--config", OVPN_FILE,
            "--auth-user-pass", PASSFILE,
            "--dev", "proton0",
            "--dev-type", "tun"
        ], stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

which both yield the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\protonvpn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\protonvpn_cli\cli.py", line 73, in main
    cli()
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\protonvpn_cli\cli.py", line 114, in cli
    connection.fastest(protocol)
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\protonvpn_cli\connection.py", line 163, in fastest
    openvpn_connect(fastest_server, protocol)
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\protonvpn_cli\connection.py", line 463, in openvpn_connect
    subprocess.Popen([
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Anyone able to help me? I've been struggling all day with this and have been unable to find a fix. (by the way, I'm very new to python)

Edit: Upon trying to print "f" from the original module it returns this - "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\\.pvpn-cli\ovpn.log' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>". I tried inputting the name into an explorer tab and I received an error, but upon removing the double slashes I was taken to the file. I'm quite certain the double slashes are supposed to be there but could this be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you run the openvpn command directly on your terminal? Have you verified that the OVPN_FILE and PASSFILE files *actually* exist? What happens when you hardcode the actual absolute path? It looks like it is failing to find those files.

Comment: Not sure about your first question, Ill let you know later when I can get back on my computer. I've verified that those files exist 100% and I've hard-coded the path and have recieved the same error as well.

Comment: Does it exist? Is it in the path? If you open a command prompt, and type `openvpn`, does it work?

Comment: Yes I've checked numerous times and the file is there, and it returns the proper path to the "ovpn.log" file which most definitely exists. When typing "protonvpn" it returns the general help menu. To receive the error I've detailed above, I type "protonvpn connect" which puts me through a few dialogs, or "protonvpn connect -f -p UDP" which connects me to the fastest server on UDP without dialogs.

Comment: OpenVPN is an actual program, do you have it installed? The `with open(..., "w+") as f:` line obviously continues/creates a file, but that won't miraculously install OpenVPN for you. https://openvpn.net/download-open-vpn/, perhaps https://openvpn.net/community-downloads-2/

Comment: No I don't have OpenVPN installed, which I will try and do right now, but I don't precisely see where having OpenVPN installed plays a factor in writing to/creating a text log?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor - it simply runs a program, capturing its output and error messages. It's not the logfile what's causes your error but the missing openvpn.exe.

Comment: Upon installing the Windows version of OpenVPN from your first link I'm still receiving the same error.